# CSS percentage position minus a pixel

Tags: css

Is there a way to do the following in plain CSS?

```
.item {
    width: 85% - 1px;
}
```

In other words, I want the item to be 85% width, minus one pixel (ignore a border).

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Tried https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc?

Comment: If all are doing is ignoring a border I must ask...are you using `box-sizing:border-box`?...makes things simpler all round. But otherwise `calc` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a CSS `calc` function.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

In your case, it would look like this

```
width: calc(85% - 1px);
```

Answer (score 3):

Though it won't work in legacy browsers

```
width: calc(85% - 1px);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe use `box-sizing: border-box`?

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

```css
div{
  height: 50px;
  width: 85%;
  border: 1px solid #f00;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 15px auto;
}

.box-sizing{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<div class="box-sizing"></div>
```